# Enable accents in Scrapy's JSON exporting?

Tags: css, json, scrapy

I'm using Python 2.7 and Scrapy 1.3
My Scrapy code is:

```
import scrapy

class CinemaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cinema"
    allowed_domains = ['cineroxy.com.br']
    start_urls = [
        'http://cineroxy.com.br/programacao-brisamar',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        movie_names = response.css('.titulo p::text').extract()
        for movie_name in movie_names:
            yield {
                'name': movie_name.strip()
            }
```

I execute it like this:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>scrapy runspider cinema_scraper.py -o movies.json
```

Results in:

```
[
{"name": "A Bailarina"},
{"name": "Assassins Creed - O Filme"},
{"name": "Cinquenta Tons Mais Escuros"},
{"name": "Minha M\u00e3e \u00e9 uma Pe\u00e7a 2"},
{"name": "Moana - Um Mar de Aventura"},
{"name": "Os Penetras 2 - Quem D\u00e1 Mais?"},
{"name": "Quatro Vidas de Um Cachorro"},
{"name": "Resident Evil 6: O \u00daltimo Cap\u00edtulo"},
{"name": "xXx: Reativado"}
]
```

How to fix the accents in

```
Minha M\u00e3e \u00e9 uma Pe\u00e7a 2
Os Penetras 2 - Quem D\u00e1 Mais?
Resident Evil 6: O \u00daltimo Cap\u00edtulo
```

?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING) option:

```
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
```

You can set it in your settings.py, or in custom_settings spider attribute, or via command line:

```
scrapy runspider cinema_scraper.py -s FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING=utf8 -o movies.json
```

Comment: I changed the `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = None` to `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = 'utf-8'` in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\settings\default_settings.py` and worked! Thanks!

Comment: Changing default_settin‌​gs.py is usually a bad idea - if you upgrade or reinstall Scrapy changes won't persist. If you want to avoid writing FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING in command line, and you don't have settings.py file (i.e. you're not using Scrapy projects), then a better way is to use set custom_settings spider attribute: add `custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING': 'utf-8'}` line after `name = "cinema"`

Comment: I do have **settings.py** but every try on writing **FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING** on it, was unsuccessful. I tryed writing that line into my code, but did not worked too. I'm currently using the **command line** you suggested and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8'`, but is very important to use this option and his value without spaces:

```
scrapy runspider cinema_scraper.py -s FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='utf-8' -o movies.json
```